# Very slow external list based on SQL Server

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, external-list, bdc

I am using SharePoint 2016 on premises. This is a new farm with installation done just now. I created BDC to fetch data from SQL Server view. That view contain less than 8000 records. Then I created External Content Type in SPD and applied a filter so it will fetch around 3300 records. Problem is when I load that external list in browser it takes 50 seconds to show those 3300 records.

Although the view contain more than 30 fields but at this time I am just displaying three field but still it takes a long time. Is this normal?

If I query that view directly in SQL Server then it only takes 1 second.

Both SharePoint and that SQL Server are in same premises and network.

How to speed up this process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the SharePoint 2013 developer dashboard to monitor the access process.

You can check which step used a lot of time.

This is a [reference](https://www.petri.com/sharepoint-2013-developer-dashboard-introduction) about how to use the SharePoint 2013 Developer Dashboard.

Besides, you can also use the fiddler to monitor the Loading process.

This is a [reference](https://www.techarex.net/blog/microsoft-sharepoint/configuring-sharepoint-2013-for-fiddler/) about how to use the fiddler to monitor loading process.

Comment: Good idea about using developer dashboard. I have seen ULS logs and didn't find anything unusual just a lot of calls to SQL Server for each record but let's see what DD has to say.

Comment: Developer Dashboard is showing a lot of these entries in "Service Calls" tab. I wonder how can I make it stop?   `ExecuteWcfOperationhttp://www.microsoft.com/Office/2009/BusinessDataCatalog/BusinessDataCatalogSharedService`